# Remove empty sub plots in matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I determine whether a subplot (`AxesSubplot`) is empty or not? I would like to deactivate empty axes of empty subplots and remove completely empty rows.

For instance, in this figure only two subplots are filled and the remaining subplots are empty.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create figure wit 3 rows and 7 cols; don't squeeze is it one list
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 7, squeeze=False)
x = [1,2]
y = [3,4]

# plot stuff only in two SubAxes; other axes are empty
axes[0][1].plot(x, y)
axes[1][2].plot(x, y)

# save figure
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

Note: It is mandatory to set `squeeze` to `False`.

Basically I want a sparse figure. Some subplots in rows can be empty, but they should be deactivated (no axes must be visible). Completely empty rows must be removed and must not be set to invisible.

Comment: You could use subplot2grid?

Comment: I think it would be possible, but how does it solve my problem determining empty subplots?

Comment: See my answer to see if it applies to your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of achieving what you require is to use matplotlibs [subplot2grid](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) feature. Using this you can set the total size of the grid (3,7 in your case) and choose to only plot data in certain subplots in this grid. I have adapted your code below to give an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2]
y = [3,4]

fig = plt.subplots(squeeze=False)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 7), (0, 1))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 7), (1, 2))

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

This gives the following graph:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Subplot2grid, in effect, does give you a list of axes. In your original question you use `fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 7, squeeze=False)` and then use `axes[0][1].plot(x, y)` to specifiy which subplot your data will be plotted in. That is the same as what subplot2grid does, apart from it only shows the subplots with data in them which you have defined.

So take `ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 7), (0, 1))` in my answer above, here I have specified the shape of the 'grid' which is 3 by 7. That means I can have 21 subplots in that grid if I wanted, exactly like you original code. The difference is that your code displays all the subplots whereas subplot2grid does not. The `(3,7)` in `ax1 = ...` above specifies the shape of the whole grid and the `(0,1)` specifies where **in** that grid the subplot will be shown.

You can use any position the subplot wherever you like within that 3x7 grid. You can also fill all 21 spaces of that grid with subplots that have data in them if you require by going all the way up to `ax21 = plt.subplot2grid(...)`.

Comment: This `fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 7, squeeze=False)` also an list of axes. How do I get a similiar list of axes by using `subplot2grid`?

Comment: When you say 'list of axes' do you mean that using `fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 7, squeeze=False)` lets you do `axes[0][1].plot(x, y)` and choose which subplot the plot is actually shown in?

Comment: I've updated my answer anyway to try and answer your comment (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help and explaination. It does solve my problem.

Comment: This seems similar to the `add_subplot` function on figures.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `fig.delaxes()` method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create figure wit 3 rows and 7 cols; don't squeeze is it one list
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 7, squeeze=False)
x = [1,2]
y = [3,4]

# plot stuff only in two SubAxes; other axes are empty
axes[0][1].plot(x, y)
axes[1][2].plot(x, y)

# delete empty axes
for i in [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
          18, 19, 20]:
    fig.delaxes(axes.flatten()[i])

# save figure
plt.savefig('image.png')
plt.show(block=False)
```